# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() returning null

Tags: android, rtsp, rtp, android-video-player

I have to make an android MJPEG player that receives RTP packets, gets the payload, and displays the image on the screen.

This is how I'm getting my packet:

**RTP.java**

```
socket.receive(receive_packet);
rtp_packet = new RtpPacket(receive_packet.getData(), receive_packet.getLength());
```

**RtpPacket.java**

```
//Load header
header = new byte[12];
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    header[i] = packet[i];

//Load payload
int payload_length = size - 12;
payload = new byte[payload_length];
for (int i = 12; i < payload_length; i ++)
    payload[i-12] = packet[i];

//This is actually handled in the activity view, but it's here for testing purposes
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(payload, 0, payload_length);
```

For some reason, bmp is always null.  I'm checked my payload and it seems fine; It's a byte[] array, usually between 2000-4000, and it looks like [-1,-40,-32,-0,16.. etc].  I am certain the header size of the RTP packet is supposed to be 12.

Does anyone have insights into how I can fix this?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity you could use ``decodeByteArray(packet, 12, packet.length - 12)``.

Comment: @harism I don't know why but that actually solved the problem.  If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as solved.